# How to include a resource file in the Jar file generated by Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, jar, include, resources

I'm using NB6.7 to auto generate an executable jar file for my project, how and where to tell NB to include a certain resource into the result jar file ? I know if I put the resource in the "lib" directory, NB will put it into "dist/lib/", but what I want is to include the resource **within** the final executable jar, where in NB do I specify that ?

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it : put the resource file in the src dir.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to add arbitrary file/folders to arbitrary location within the jar, without setting up source folders.

NetBeans will, by default, create [`build.xml`](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/SimpleEE6App/build.xml?rev=78) at project root.
We can override the `-pre-jar` target to copy the files and `-post-jar` target to cleanup.

For example, to copy "res/resource.ext" into "myres/resource.ext" within the jar, add these target to `build.xml`:

```
<target name="-pre-jar">
   <!-- Single file -->
   <copy file="res/resoure.ext" todir="${build.dir}/classes/myres" />
   <!-- Folder(s) -->
   <copy todir="${build.dir}/classes/myres"><fileset dir="res"/></copy>
</target>

<target name="-post-jar">
   <delete dir="${build.dir}/classes/myres/resource.ext" />
   <delete dir="${build.dir}/classes/myres"/>
</target>
```

Since this is Ant, you have great control.
You can [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971187/ant-renaming-while-copying-file) file, [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433588/retrieve-value-from-text-file-and-replace-a-string-constant-in-another-file-with) file content (e.g. [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918141/replace-property-in-a-xml-file-using-ant) version or timestamp), [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374324/how-to-encode-java-files-in-utf-8-using-apache-ant) charset, or run [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241966/ant-unzip-multiple-files) [operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments) that is not possible with simple inclusion.

I am using NetBeans version 8, but as long as the project is compatible it is likely to work.

---

Alternatively, use an automated project such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), that gives you even more control on the build process, at cost of IDE features such as automatic single file recompile.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by...
Go to your project name which is normally on the left hand side of the screen. 
Whatever your project name is,
you have to right click on it and then go to the properties of that.  [which is normally at the end in menu item]
Then one window will open in that go to the Libraries.
In that you will find 
1)ADD PROJECT 
2)ADD Libraries
3)ADD JAR FILE

then include the jar / Libraries / folder.

so that will add automatically to your project.
Which will include in lib folder automatically so you don't have to include always.

Hope this help you,