# Use Ant for running program with command line arguments

Tags: java, ant

My program getting command line arguments. How can I pass it when I use Ant?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Extending [Richard Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments/3730898#3730898)'s answer.

Here's the `ant` task to run any program (including, but not limited to Java programs):

```
<target name="run">
   <exec executable="name-of-executable">
      <arg value="${arg0}"/>
      <arg value="${arg1}"/>
   </exec>
</target>
```

Here's the task to run a Java program from a `.jar` file:

```
<target name="run-java">
   <java jar="path for jar">
      <arg value="${arg0}"/>
      <arg value="${arg1}"/>
   </java>
</target>
```

You can invoke either from the command line like this:

```
ant -Darg0=Hello -Darg1=World run
```

Make sure to use the `-Darg` syntax; if you ran this:

```
ant run arg0 arg1
```

then `ant` would try to run targets `arg0` and `arg1`.

Comment: Is the "name-of-executable" the path for jar?

Comment: The exec task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) will run any arbitrary program.  The java task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) will execute a java program.

Comment: what does the `run` do at the end

Answer (score 30):

If you do not want to handle separate properties for each possible argument, I suggest you'd use:

```xml
<arg line="${args}"/>
```

You can check if the property is not set using a specific target with an `unless` attribute and inside do:

```xml
<input message="Type the desired command line arguments:" addProperty="args"/>
```

Putting it all together gives:

```xml
<target name="run" depends="compile, input-runargs" description="run the project">
  <!-- You can use exec here, depending on your needs -->
  <java classname="Main">
    <arg line="${args}"/>
  </java>
</target>
<target name="input-runargs" unless="args" description="prompts for command line arguments if necessary">
  <input addProperty="args" message="Type the desired command line arguments:"/>
</target>
```

You can use it as follows:

```sh
ant
ant run
ant run -Dargs='--help'
```

The first two commands will prompt for the command-line arguments, whereas the latter won't.

Comment: I like how you proposed a solution without the -Dargs

Answer (score 13):

The only effective mechanism for passing parameters into a build is to use Java properties:

```
ant -Done=1 -Dtwo=2
```

The following example demonstrates how you can check and ensure the expected parameters have been passed into the script

```
<project name="check" default="build">

    <condition property="params.set">
        <and>
            <isset property="one"/>
            <isset property="two"/>
        </and>
    </condition>

    <target name="check">
        <fail unless="params.set">
        Must specify the parameters: one, two
        </fail>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="check">
        <echo>
        one = ${one}
        two = ${two}
        </echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: How does xml look like when I don't know how many args I will have?

Comment: What if number of args isn't constant?

Comment: if number of args is not constant, then probably the best u can do is ant -Dvarargs="Hello World. It is Good to Meet You!" run

Comment: Really helpful to have an entire file as a working exercise - we never did work out why parameter passing didn't work in our original file, but successfully modified the working file to include all the needed functionality without breaking the parameters...

Comment: What if I need just pass sort of switcher (e.g. -f in bash commands), i.e. option without value? Looks like '-Drelease' or '-Drelease=' triggers error re missing property value

Comment: @monitor You cannot easily create your own flags (example: -f) for the ANT process. Setting Java properties is an approximation to parameter passing into the ANT script.

Answer (score 4):

Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it?

If you're attempting to invoke the program using the `<exec>` task you might do the following:

```
<exec executable="name-of-executable">
  <arg value="arg0"/>
  <arg value="arg1"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end is make a batch file to extract the CLASSPATH from the ant file, then run java directly using this:

In my build.xml:

```
<target name="printclasspath">
    <pathconvert property="classpathProp" refid="project.class.path"/>
    <echo>${classpathProp}</echo>
</target>
```

In another script called 'run.sh':

```
export CLASSPATH=$(ant -q printclasspath | grep echo | cut -d \  -f 7):build
java "$@"
```

It's no longer cross-platform, but at least it's relatively easy to use, and one could provide a .bat file that does the same as the run.sh.  It's a very short batch script.   It's not like migrating the entire build to platform-specific batch files.

I think it's a shame there's not some option in ant whereby you could do something like:

```
ant -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

mpirun uses this type of syntax; ssh also can use this syntax I think.