# Passing optional path arguments to ant

Tags: ant, command-line-arguments, argument-passing, optional-arguments

I have an ant task that uses an apply task to run a script on a group of files.

I have a directory structure resultant of something like this:
`mkdir -p a/{b,c,d,e}/f`

Normally (if I pass no arguments), I would like ant to run on all `f`s.
That is, if I called `ant mytask`, it should process: `a/b/f, a/c/f, a/d/f, a/e/f`. This already works using apply and patternsets.

However, when I pass it an optional argument called `foo`, it should only call the script on `a/foo/f`.

So if I called `ant mytask -foo b`, it should process `a/b/f` only, and not the others.

I have read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments), which explains ways of passing arguments, and I have looked at the ant documentation regarding [properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html), and [conditionals](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html). But I am still unable to piece them together in a way that works.

Also, I do not want to use one of the suggestions from the SO above which called for arguments like this:

```
<arg value="${arg0}"/>
<arg value="${arg1}"/>
```

I want to be able to call it as `ant mytask -foo valueoffoo` for any arbitrary `foo`.

Thanks.

---

I tried martin clayton's suggestion below and have code like:

```
<target name="mytask">
  <property name="foo" value="*" />
  <apply executable="perl">
    <arg value="somescript"/>
    <dirset id="them" dir="a">
      <include name="${foo}/*/f" />
    </dirset>
  </apply>
</target>
```

The above does what I want.

Note 1: In my actual code I use a patternset instead of dirset but it should work the same.

Note 2: In my original question I said the directory structure was `a/{b,c,d,e}/f`. It is in fact a bit more complicated, hence the `*` in the include above. I omitted that the first time around because it did not seem relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this - your example Ant command line mentions a target `mytask` and an arbitrary `foo`, but your sample buildfile is for a target called foo?  Do you need to pass in an arbitrary sub-path perhaps?  Or is it just one arbitrary directory level?

Comment: @martin clayton : Oh sorry, you're right that is confusing. I fixed my question.

Comment: So, by default, the include pattern is `*/*/f` - which parts of that do you want to be able to override from the command line?  The `${foo}` part, or the middle `*` - or both perhaps?

Comment: Well, presumably if I learn to do the ${foo} part I could adapt it if I were to later need the middle as well. For now though it's just the ${foo}. 

I am guessing if I needed both the property could be set with value="*/*" or I could have two properties set to *. (If this sentence doesn't make sense ignore it, not too relevant).

Comment: So what happens when you run something like `ant -Dfoo=d` with the above buildfile?

Comment: Aha, so it works now. Not sure what was wrong earlier but it looks good. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this - albeit with a slightly different command-line syntax -
using a property 'override'.

First, in the buildfile, construct your fileset or dirset from a property `foo`,
something like this:

```
<property name="foo" value="*" />
<dirset id="them" dir="a">
    <include name="${foo}/f" />
</dirset>
```

This will give you your default behaviour - processing all
subdirectories of `a` that themselves have a subdirectory `f`.

Now, if you run Ant like this:

```
ant -Dfoo=d
```

Only directory `a/d/f` will be processed.

This works because Ant properties are not mutable - well, not normally anyway -
so the command-line definition of `foo` prevents the one within the buildfile from being used.