# Java, main command line arguments and Ant build file

Tags: java, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Ant for running program with command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments)

I have written a java program that gets as command line arguments several file names (that are inputted into `String[] args` array of the main.
Now I need to write an Ant build file.
How do I make this command:

```
ant run SampleFile1.txt SampleFile2.txt ...
```

Get those arguments and pass them to my main?

Here's my sample Ant file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="MyProgram" default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="MyProgram.MainClass"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
 </target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

   <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>

            </manifest>

        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
//now when I run it here, I want it to get the arguments I input when I do ant run. for example: ant run file1.txt, file2.txt <- I want those to go to my String[] args of the main 
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it gives me error Target "File.txt" does not exist in the project "SampleProj".

Comment: What was the command that you executed?

Comment: java MyProgram file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: Do you even have a file called `build.xml`? Can you post that. By default, runnint `ant` executes the build system in this file. We can't help you without knowing what that file looks like.

Comment: @DavidW. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a bit of a change in the `<java>` task:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="${file1}"/>
        <arg value="${file2}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Now, you have two new parameters: `file1` and `file2` You can pass those from the command line like this:

```
$ ant -Dfile1=foo.txt-Dfile2=bar.txt run
```

Ant takes a list of targets, and you are executing target *run*. The `-D` parameters are the properties you're passing to your program.

I recommend that you put default parameters in your program like this:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <property name="file1" value="bar.txt"/>
    <property name="file2" value="foo.txt"/>
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <args value="${file1}"/>
        <args value="${file2}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

This way, if you don't pass any parameters, it will use your default parameters of `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`. Remember that properties set on the command line with the `-D` parameter override the value of those properties set in the `build.xml` file itself. Once a property is set, it can never be changed.

Comment: In my homework, I have to run the file like this:
"ant run File1.txt File2.txt"
So is there a way to make it run without the -D parameter?

Comment: All non-parameterized arguments used in the Ant command are _targets_. It might be possible to do a bit of trickery to finagle Ant to do what you want. The Ant command line can be found in the ${sun.java.command} property. It might be possible to pull out the targets from there. Ant runs the non-targeted tasks before looking at the tasks, so it may be possible to put your `<java>` task outside any targets, and then parse the command line, pull out your other arguments, execute `<java>` task, and ignore the _targets not found message_. Better off writing a small shell script to do that for you.