# How to pass several parameters to a bat file that invokes ANT

Tags: batch-file, ant, parameter-passing

Could you please help me with the following problem? I have `custom.bat` file. I set 3 parameters every time for it. I want automate this process. I've tried the following command `custom.bat < test.txt`. `test.txt` file contains the following:

```
no
form_app
no
```

But only first parameter is redirected to the custom.bat file. How can I redirect all parameters to the custom.bat file? This is my batch file:

```
@echo off
call ..\setenv.cmd
set JAVA_HOME=%LYRA_JAVA_HOME%
set tmp=%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=.;%CLASSPATH%
ant\bin\ant.bat -f custom.xml -quiet %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 
set CLASSPATH=%tmp%
```

Comment: This is custom.bat file
@echo off
call ..\setenv.cmd
set JAVA_HOME=%LYRA_JAVA_HOME%
set tmp=%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=.;%CLASSPATH%
ant\bin\ant.bat -f custom.xml -quiet %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
set CLASSPATH=%tmp%

Comment: Is it not simply `custom.bat no form_app no`?

Comment: @TripeHound, no, it will think those are build targets. Should be `custom.bat -DsomeName=no -DsomeName=form_app -DsomeName=no`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Ant for running program with command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730880/use-ant-for-running-program-with-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works