# Create Kotlin annotation from Java @Test TestNG annotation

Tags: kotlin, annotations, testng

I am using Java TestNG annotation:

```
@Test(groups = ['integration'])
```

And I would like to create Kotlin annotation like:

```
@IntegrationTest
```

Is it doable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of now Kotlin language doesn't have builtin tools that enable such use case.

You can resort to the [annotation processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385628/how-to-write-a-java-annotation-processor) technique: write an annotation processor that replaces your custom `@IntegrationTest` with `@Test` from TestNG.

One drawback of annotation processing is that a processor is a black box to the tooling. For example, IDE won't treat the methods annotated with `@IntegrationTest` as tests because it doesn't know that they are going to be post-processed later.

Also annotation processing is a JVM-specific tool, so it isn't supported on other platforms.