# Replace the token in file with contents of other file using ant script

Tags: ant

I have 2 files input file and replace file. I want to replace a token(`@@CONTENT_TO_REPLACE@@`) in input file with all the contents of replace file.

Input file:

```
<amxdata_base:Enterprise
    xmlns:amxdata="http://tibco.com/amxadministrator/command/line/types"
    xmlns:amxdata_base="http://tibco.com/amxadministrator/command/line/types_base"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    <!-- Enterprise level Substitution variables -->

    @@CONTENT_TO_REPLACE@@

</amxdata_base:Enterprise>
```

Replace file:

```
<SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="JMS_CONNECTION_TOPIC_FACTORY" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENT_JMS_CONNECTION_TOPIC_FACTORY@" /> 
<SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="JMS_CONNECTION_QUEUE_FACTORY" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENT_JMS_CONNECTION_QUEUE_FACTORY@" />
```

Resulant file:

```
<amxdata_base:Enterprise
    xmlns:amxdata="http://tibco.com/amxadministrator/command/line/types"
    xmlns:amxdata_base="http://tibco.com/amxadministrator/command/line/types_base"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    <!-- Enterprise level Substitution variables -->

    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="JMS_CONNECTION_TOPIC_FACTORY" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENT_JMS_CONNECTION_TOPIC_FACTORY@" /> 
    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="JMS_CONNECTION_QUEUE_FACTORY" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENT_JMS_CONNECTION_QUEUE_FACTORY@" /> 

</amxdata_base:Enterprise>
```

Comment: See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433588/retrieve-value-from-text-file-and-replace-a-string-constant-in-another-file-with