# How to encode Java files in UTF-8 using Apache Ant?

Tags: java, ant, encoding, build.xml

In my build.xml file I fetch some Java files by cxf. Some of these Java files need to be encoded in UTF-8. How can I use Ant to change the encoding to UTF-8?

PS: I found instructions for how to set the encoding for javac to UTF-8, but prior to javac I need Java files to be in UTF-8. Otherwise I get an error:

> warning: unmappable character for encoding utf-8

Here is my code:

```
<macrodef name="lpwservice">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="package"/>
    <sequential>
        <property name="wsdlfile" value="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl"/>

        <mkdir dir="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl"/>
        <get src="${lpw.baseuri.cxf}/@{name}?wsdl" dest="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl.new"/>
        <if>
            <and>
                <filesmatch file1="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl" file2="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl.new"/>
                <uptodate targetfile="${portal.basedir}/lpw-wsdl.jar" srcfile="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl"/>
            </and>
            <then>
                <echo message="${wsdlfile} is up to date" level="info"/>
                <delete file="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl.new"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl needs update" level="info"/>
                <move file="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl.new" tofile="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl" overwrite="true" />
                <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true" failonerror="true">
                    <arg value="-client"/>
                    <arg value="-d"/>
                    <arg value="${portal.basedir}/lpw/src"/>
                    <arg value="${portal.basedir}/lpw/wsdl/@{name}.wsdl"/>
                    <classpath>
                        <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
                    </classpath>
                </java>
            </else>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

What should I do here to make

```
<java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true" failonerror="true">
```

to encode java files in utf-8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ant's [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task has attributes `encoding` and `outputencoding`.

#### Single Java File

```
<copy file="myJavaFile.java" tofile="myJavaFile.java" overwrite="true"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1" outputencoding="UTF-8" />
```

#### All Java Files in a Directory

```
<property name="source.dir" location="/path/to/java/files" />

<copy todir="${source.dir}" overwrite="true"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1" outputencoding="UTF-8">
  <fileset dir="${source.dir}" includes="*.java" />
</copy>
```

Simply change `ISO-8859-1` to the encoding format of your Java files.

Comment: a big thanks for your answer. I'm kind of close to solve this but I still haven't managed to make this work. My code is as following... I add the code in my question above here...

Comment: if (areSame(source, dest)) {            // copying the "same" file to itself will corrupt the file, so we skip it            log(project, "Skipping (self) copy of " + source +  " to " + dest);            return;        } It is not going to work!