# Ant: unzip multiple files

Tags: ant, unzip

How to unzip multiple files with Ant?
I am using:

```
<unzip dest="./out">
    <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </patternset>
    <fileset dir="./in">
        <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
</unzip>
```

From the output it looks like ANT is correctly finding my files but nothing gets extracted:

> ```
> [unzip] Expanding: c:\temp\in\test1.zip into c:\temp\out
> [unzip] Expanding: c:\temp\in\test2.zip into c:\temp\out
> ```
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 0 seconds

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you check the ./out dir? and are the zip files in the ./in dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)

> PatternSets are used to select files to extract *from* the archive. If no patternset is used, all files are extracted.

My guess is thus that your zip files don't contain any zip file, and thus nothing is extracted, since you told Ant to only extract zip files from your zip files.

Comment: In my directory I have test1.zip and test2.zip.  I want ant to extract everything inside them and save it to out

Comment: Have you read my answer? Why are you using a patternset? The patternset you're using says to Ant: "I want to only extract files named *.zip from the zip files. The other files shouldn't be extracted". Remove this patternset.

Comment: I think I just figured out, based on your comment of course.  I thought patternset was to select what files to unzip and not what to unzip from the zip files. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as I removed patternset, it worked:
<unzip dest="./out">
   <fileset dir="./in">
   <include name="**/*.zip"/>
   </fileset>
</unzip>